# Help casting a pointer to a union

Tags: c, pointers, casting, unions

I am working on C firmware project. I have a union that is defined as,

```
typedef union {
    unsigned long value;
    unsigned char bytes[4];
} LONGVALUE;
```

I also have a function that has this prototype,

```
char sendHexToASCII_UART(char *msg, int cnt);
```

and a variable of type LONGVALUE defined as,

```
LONGVALUE countAddr;
```

THE PROBLEM: 
I fill the individual bytes of the union variable with values from an array (tempBuff1), I then want to pass the address of the first element in the union to a function that will print it to the UART. On my function call `sendHexToASCII_UART((int *)countAddr.bytes[0], 4);`, I get a compiler warning saying "cast to pointer from integer of different size". Can someone explain why I am getting this and how I can make it go away? NOTE: Changing the (int *) cast to (char *) causes the same warning.

```
countAddr.bytes[0] = tempBuff1[COUNT_ADDR - PWRD_ADDRESS];
countAddr.bytes[1] = tempBuff1[COUNT_ADDR - PWRD_ADDRESS + 1];
countAddr.bytes[2] = tempBuff1[COUNT_ADDR - PWRD_ADDRESS + 2];
countAddr.bytes[3] = tempBuff1[COUNT_ADDR - PWRD_ADDRESS + 3];
sendHexToASCII_UART((int *)countAddr.bytes[0], 4);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just:

```
sendHexToASCII_UART((char *)countAddr.bytes, 4);
```

or even better:

```
sendHexToASCII_UART((char *)countAddr.bytes, sizeof(countAddr.bytes));
```

Comment: Then I get: `warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'sendHexToASCII_UART' differ in signedness`

Comment: I changed to (unsigned char *) and I still get the same `differ in sidnedness` warning

Comment: @Jordan S: that's because I'm an idiot.  See newly-updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

sendHexToASCII_UART((int *)(&countAddr.bytes[0]), 4);

or:

sendHexToASCII_UART((int *)(countAddr.bytes), 4);

Answer (score 0):

The value of the expression

```
countAddr.bytes[0]
```

is an unsigned char (the first byte in your array), which you cast to an int pointer, hence the warning. As Oli said, you must remove the `[0]` to get a pointer to the array, which is what you want.

Comment: Then I get: `warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'sendHexToASCII_UART' differ in signedness`

Comment: Right. Your best bet is probably to use a cast here, as suggested by Alex, since you really want to change the interpretation of your byte sequence.

Answer (score 0):

or try this without creating variable of LONGVALUE type

```
sendHexToASCII_UART(((LONGVALUE *)0)->bytes, 4);
```